# An error opening a new project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've downloaded the JDK and Eclipse and started learning how to code in Java.

All of a sudden when I try to open a new project, I get this screen saying "select a wizard" with nothing to select. It won't let me continue.

I uninstalled and re-installed the software (although it worked fine before) but the problem remained.

What can I do?

[image: the error]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse did you download and install?

Comment: Are you selecting a `Java Project` from the `New` menu?

Comment: This is the Eclipse 4.5.0, and JDK 8u65 win-x64. And I do file->new->project

Comment: When @PM77-1 inlined the imaged it has been compressed/sized down so you can't see it now, but you could clearly see a black point in the middle of nowhere on the original screens. This is clearly an UI bug , not a misuse of Eclipse

Comment: @Dici - restored the link

Comment: @PM77-1 the intent was good, the consequence unpredictable :)

Comment: @PM77-1 I inlined the image the way it would have been inlined if the OP had sufficient privileges to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but ... I'd say it is just a problem of the window size. Try resizing the "New Project" dialog to show its actual content :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use another perspective, for example Java, JAVA EE
go to in menu **Window** -> **Show View** -> **Other** and select the perspective you like

Or access menu File New Project and select one time of the project

Comment: I don't think you can open pespectives from the Show View menu. Perhaps you meant Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Java?

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded a wrong version of Eclipse. You can find the right one here

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

[image: Usefull image here]

Comment: On what basis do you think OP has wrong version of Eclipse? I have never seen the OP's error, but the rest of Eclipse looks ok in the screenshot.